# You can take the total width of a document for a table itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pdf, itext

it is possible that my table "itextsharp" can take the total width of the document ??

As seen in the picture my board starts farther from the edge.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default width of a table is 80% of the available width. You can change the by using:

```
table.WidthPercentage = 100;
```

Of course: this still isn't the full width of the page. If you want to use the full width of the page, you have to set the left and right margin to 0.